# If I move a 120v breaker, do I also have to move the neutral wire?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, neutral

I need to rearrange the breakers in my main panel box in order to make room for a generator breaker. If I move a single pole 120V breaker from the left side of the panel box to the right side, do I also have to move the associated neutral wire for that breaker from the left side neutral bar over to the right side neutral bar? Or can I leave the neutrals alone when I move the breakers?